# iOS AppStore app rejected because the app include a link to registration. How can I solve?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

We have created an app for an easy mail message system. New users have to create a new account on our website, before they can use our app. The creating of a new account is free. On the login form in the app is a button, which link to the registration form on our website. The review team has reject our app, because this link is not compliant with the guideline rule 11.13. The review team ask us to remove this button. But without this button is the app useless for new users, if they don't know where they can create a new account. I have asked the review team, if they accept our app, when we include the registration form within the app. But they are giving no answers to concept questions.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: There's a 2013 WWDC session about how to create a successful app, and it describes how asking the user to register as the very first step will make them delete your app immediately. It also gives examples of what you can do.

Answer (score 3):

I think Apple wants you to make account creation integrated into your app rather than providing a link to account creation on your site.

You could build an account creation interface into your app, or (maybe) alternatively, wrap the account creation UI in a `UIWebView` or similar control.

See http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140038/violation-of-apple-review-guild-1113

Basically, keep it all in the app.

Comment: I would refrain from using a UIWebView because of issues regarding authentication and possible redirects to a secure login page. The service SHOULD provide an appropriate login API suitable for communication with devices. Then, there should be no problems using a suitable HTTP request to accomplish a login with NSURLConnection or NSURLSession.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You mean, I should insert the web form from our website easy in a UiWebView control in our app? And this will Apple accept?

Comment: @Sebastian Ha, just in time  ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper if the service provides the API you might as well implement it natively

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos Yes, exactly - this is the way to go.

Comment: @Sebastian I cannot tell you whether Apple will accept a wrapped `UIWebView` in general. In the past they have let it slide for a few of my clients' projects but I cannot say whether they will continue to do so. I think their main concern is that the wrapped web view "looks like" part of the app (ie it doesn't break the app experience)

Comment: @Sebastian to clarify, I am not saying you will get away with a `UIWebView` for sure, but I do think you have an excellent chance if you can make the `UIWebView` look like it is really part of the app (ie use a special stylesheet, use the mobile version of your site, etc)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper indeed, but what if the API doesn't exist and the existing user registration page is a classic ASP page from 1999? :-P

Comment: Time to make a few adjustments to the web service ;)  @Sebastian you might be interested in this statement on Apple's official dev site: [UIWebView does not directly support authentication](https://devforums.apple.com/message/904426#904426.) Hope that helps. :)

Comment: Gives a free API for the creating an account or the registration process anywhere?

Comment: @Sebastian think of how you interact with your DB (ie through a web service) in the rest of your app. Ideally, you should use the same approach to allow user registration. Less ideally, you could _try_ to wrap an existing authentication page in a web view.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is, when I insert the user registration in the app with my php rest interface and the user interface (text fields as i.e. name, email etc.) add directly in the app, then are updates and changes in the registration process later not impossible, without edit the app. If I insert the registration website in a UIWebView, then I can make changes later very easy. Or what you mean?